# How to use the mdio-bitbang, mdio-gpio linux driver to read phy register

Tags: linux

I want to read the phy register using mdio mdio-bitbang, mdio-gpio linux driver. The phy is connected to the gpio pins (10, 11) on the mpc8308 controller and it complies to the mdio specification of IEEE 802.3 Clause 45 but it is not a ethernet phy.

What should be the node entry in the dts fie and how do I access the phy registers from the linux userpsace. I am using a pretty old kernel 2.6.29.